# Graph isomorphism checking using BFS

Tags: graph-theory, breadth-first-search, isomorphism

Is there any fast algorithm to check the isomorphism and find the mapping between two rooted undirected graphs by BFS? Since my two input graphs are rooted I am just assuming that BFS can find it out quicker if they are not isomorphic. Any help/clue is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that you can do it with BFS cause its an unsolve problem in computer science. look at : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem

Comment: It is not unsolvable! The available solutions are not polynomial!